# How can I display a specific property from an object in an array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I display a specific property from an object in an array using ng-repeat. The emails field is what I want to display

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "TypeId": 3,
        "Type": "Listings",
        "emails": [
            "someemail2@example.com", 
            "someemail3@example.com", 
            "someemail5@example.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

Controller:

```
myService.getEmails().then(function (emails) {
    if (emails && emails.length) {
        $scope.emailsList = emails
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in emailsList['emails'] track by $index">
    <td>
        <div class="rounded-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-12">{{ item }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$scope.emailsList` is the array of emails, change your HTML like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in emailsList[0].emails track by $index">
    <td>
        <div class="rounded-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-12">{{ item }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No. I want to only display the emails.
This results in:

{"TypeId":3,"Type":"Listings","emails":["someemail2@example.com","someemail3@example.com","someemail5@example.com"]}

Comment: What does $scope.emailsList  contain?

Comment: $scope.emailsList = [{
        "TypeId": 3,
        "Type": "Listings",
        "emails": [
            "someemail2@example.‌​com",
            "someemail3@exa‌​mple.com",
            "someemail‌​5@example.com"
        ]
    }]

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try now and let me know if it is working or not

Comment: It works. I came up with another solution.

    <tr ng-repeat="item in emailsList track by $index">
        <td>
            <div class="rounded-checkbox">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-12">{{ item.emails[$index] }}</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>

Comment: But your data structure you have specified is different. Did you try my above method? item will contain only one object.

Answer (score 0):

**This works**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in emailsList track by $index">
    <td>
        <div class="rounded-checkbox">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-12">{{ item.emails[$index] }}</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are all the emails printing? I doubt it if your $scope.emailsList = [{ "TypeId": 3, "Type": "Listings", "emails": [ "someemail2@example.‌​com", "someemail3@exa‌​mple.com", "someemail‌​5@example.com" ] }]

Comment: @Vivz Yes! All of them are being printed. Your method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416174/8349557 works too.